# How do I create between 2 and 4 players in my pyGame based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've created a rather simple game of snakes and ladders so far for a project. Currently, it has only two players but I'd like to include an option where the user inputs the number of players (2-4), then inputs all the players name, and draws the counters for them on the board. However, I'm having difficulty implementing this at the moment.

My original section of code for two players is as followed(which works perfectly fine):

```
print('''
        Welcome to Snakes N Ladders!
        Take it turns to roll the die, press SPACE to do so!
        The first player to 100 wins, but they have to land exactly on it.
        Good luck, have fun!
    '''
      )
player1Name = input("Please enter the first players name: ")
player1 = Player(player1Name)
player2Name = input("Please enter the second players name: ")
player2 = Player(player2Name)

players = [player1, player2]





def drawGrid():
    window.blit(boardImage,(0,0))
    for x in range (height):
        for y in range(width):
            if board[x][y] == player1.Pos:
                pygame.draw.circle(window, PlayerOneColour, (x * squareSize + int(squareSize/2) -10, y*squareSize +int(squareSize/2)+6) ,charSize)
            if board[x][y] == player2.Pos:
                pygame.draw.circle(window, PlayerTwoColour, (x * squareSize + int(squareSize/2) +10, y*squareSize +int(squareSize/2)+6) ,charSize)



    pygame.display.flip()
```

This uses the class Players I created before hand, the PlayerOneColour sets the colour of player1 and the same can be said for player2.

The class Players is:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.Pos = 1
        print("Player created!")

    def turn(self):
        roll = random.randint(1,6)
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        print(self.name,"rolled a",roll)
                        for i in range(self.Pos, self.Pos + roll + 1):
                            self.Pos = i
                            drawGrid()
                            time.sleep(.4)
                        print(self.name,"is now at:",self.Pos)
                        if self.Pos > 100:
                            self.Pos -= roll
                            print(self.name,"rolled a",roll,"they need to roll a",100-self.Pos,"to win!")
                    drawGrid()
                    return
```

As you can see it contains the method turn, but this is not what my question is about. It contains the player position (1) and their name. However, when I try to make a players function to create players like so:

```
def createPlayers():
        players = []
        player1Name = input("Please enter the first players name: ")
        player1 = Player(player1Name)
        players.append(player1)

        player2Name = input("Please enter the second players name: ")
        player2 = Player(player2Name)
        players.append(player2)

        print(players)    
        if numberOfPlayers == 3:
            player3Name = input("Please enter the third players name: ")
            player3 = Player(player3Name)

            players.append(player3)

        elif numberOfPlayers == 4:
            player3Name = input("Please enter the third players name: ")
            player3 = Player(player3Name)

            players.append(player3)
            player4Name = input("Please enter the fourth players name: ")
            player4 = Player(player4Name)

            players.append(player4)

        else:
            print("Please pick between 2 and 4 players.")


def drawGrid():
    window.blit(boardImage,(0,0))
    for x in range (height):
        for y in range(width)::
                if board[x][y] == player1.Pos:
                    pygame.draw.circle(window, PlayerOneColour, (x * squareSize + int(squareSize/2) -10, y*squareSize +int(squareSize/2)+6) ,charSize)
                if board[x][y] == player2.Pos:
                    pygame.draw.circle(window, PlayerTwoColour, (x * squareSize + int(squareSize/2) +10, y*squareSize +int(squareSize/2)+6) ,charSize)
                if numberOfPlayers == 3:
                    if board[x][y] == player3.Pos:
                        pygame.draw.circle(window, PlayerThreeColour, (x * squareSize + int(squareSize/2) +10, y*squareSize +int(squareSize/2)+6) ,charSize)
                if numberOfPlayers == 4:
                    if board[x][y] == player4.Pos:
                        pygame.draw.circle(window, PlayerFourColour, (x * squareSize + int(squareSize/2) +10, y*squareSize +int(squareSize/2)+6) ,charSize)
```

I know this code is very messy but I thought it was the only way, originally I had a for player in players: loop inside the drawGrid function but it either said player1 not defined or something to do with NonType objects, I thought the issue was to do with local and global variables but I don't know how to fix it, any suggestions on getting a user input to draw 2-4 players on the board would be great, if needed I can link my entire SnakesNLadders file so far.

Comment: instead of variables `player1`, `player2` use list to keep all players - and you will have `all_players[0]`, `all_players[1]`, etc. and you would have to use loops `for player in all_players` to work with all players separatelly.

Comment: you should keep player's color inside class `Player` - ie. `Player(player1Name, PlayerOneColour)` and later use `players[0]` and `player[0].color` instead of `player1` and `PlayerOneColour` to draw it - this way you can use `for`-loop to draw all players.

Comment: don't use `while True` loop inside Player. You should have loop outside all players, enemies and other objects and only send event to objects `for event in pygame.event.get(): player[0].handle_event(event)  player[1].handle_event(event)`

Comment: don't use `sleep` in games because it blocks `while True` event and it can't move other objects and it can't redraw objects on screen - ie. it can't animate other objects.

Comment: I've done that in my original code as you can see players = [player1, player2] all I want is the create players function to append player 3 and player 4 to that list and then be able to use it in the drawGrid() function, is there any way to do this? @furas

Comment: you should use list `players` with `for`-loop instead of `player1`, `player2`, etc. The same code will works if you will have 2 or 3 or 4 (or even 1000) players on list. And you should keep player's color inside class `Player`, not in separated variables `PlayerOneColour`, etc. All player's information should be inside class `Player` - name, position, color, etc. (ie. size, health, speed, etc.)

Comment: Ok, are you able to write this in code so I better understand it? Because I then need to return this list so that it can be used in the drawGrid function, but how am I meant to access a list where the elements have been created using a class?

Comment: access class property on list `players[0].name`, `players[1].name`, etc. `players[0].Pos`, `players[1].Pos`, etc. You should also keep all colors on list i. `colors = [red, blue, green, yello]` instead of separated variables `PlayerOneColour` , `PlayerTwoColour`. And then you can assign color from list to player on list  - ie. `player[1].color = color[1]` - and later you use only `player[1].color` with `player[1].Pos` so you can use it in loop `for x  in range(numbeOfPlayers): player[x].color, player[x].pos`

Comment: I have this working now, but as seen in my code when I append player 3 and player 4 to players e.g. it should be players = [player1,player2,player3,player4] when I print players I get [<main 120302303>, main<4u349395>, etc.] I know it's because the players are created with a class, but how am I meant to access the list so it gets player4 for example instead of the class object stuff?

Comment: this list is correct and to access class you have to use index `players[0].name`, `player[1].name`. It print `<main ...>` because it is default text for class. You would have to define `def __str__(self): return "text"` in class `Player` to display something different.

Comment: BTW: use `print( player1 )` and you also get `<main ... >`

Answer (score 1):

Some rules:

- if you have many elements then keep them on list and use `for`-loop.
- keep player properties inside class, not outside
- [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - ie. `lower_case_names` for variables and functions/methosd - ie. `pos` instead of `Pos`, `create_players` instead of `createPlayers`, etc.
- send values as argument instead of using external variable - ie. `create_players(number)`, and use `return` to send it back from function/method - `return players`.

---

You should keep colors on list instead of separated variables, ie.

```
colors = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (255,255,0)]
```

and class Player should get color as argument and keep it inside class

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, color, pos=1):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.pos = pos
        #self.x = x
        #self.x = y
        #self.number = number
        # etc.
        print("Player {} created!".format(name))
```

so now you can use loop to create players and assign color to player

```
colors = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (255,255,0)]

def create_players(number):

    if number < 2 or number > 4: 
        print("Please pick between 2 and 4 players.")
        return

    players = []

    for x in range(number):
        name = input("Please enter name of player #{}: ".format(x+1))
        player = Player(name, colors[x])
        players.append(player)

    return players  

players = create_players(number_of_players)
```

If you want to use words `first`, `seconds` then you can keep it on list and add to text in input

```
number_names = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']

colors = [(255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (255,255,0)]

def create_players(number):

    if number < 2 or number > 4: 
        print("Please pick between 2 and 4 players.")
        return

    players = []

    for x in number_of_players

        name = input("Please enter {} name of player: ".format(number_names[x]))

        player = Player(name, colors[x])
        players.append(player)

    return players
```

Now you can use list and `for`-loop to draw players on grid.

```
def draw_grid():
    window.blit(board_image, (0, 0))

    half_size = int(square_size/2) 
    x_offset = half_size + 10
    y_offset = half_size + 6

    for x in range(height):
        for y in range(width):

            for p in players:
                if board[x][y] == p.pos:
                    pygame.draw.circle(window, p.color, (x*squareSize + x_offset, y*squareSize + x_offset), char_size)
```

---

To get access to one selected player you can use index `[]` - `players[0].name`, `players[1].name`, etc.

But usually we have to work with all elements on list so instead of using `range(len())` and `[x])

```
 for x in range(len(players)):
     print( players[x].name )
```

we uses

```
 for p in players:
     print( p.name )
```

---

**BTW:** `print( players )` gives `[<main...>, <main...>, ...]` and it is normal. for `print( player1 )` you get also `<main...>`. You would need `__repr__` and  eventually `__str__` in class to get different text

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, color, pos=1):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.pos = pos
        print("Player {} created!".format(name))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Player: name: {}, color: {}, pos: {}>".format(self.name, self.color, self.pos)

    def __str__(self):
        #return self.__repr__() #  it is executed automatically if you don't create own `__str__`
        return "name: {}, color: {}, pos: {}".format(self.name, self.color, self.pos)
```

Comment: Ok, if I send you my code are you able to see what needs adjusting as I'm still having a few problems

Comment: It does still contain elements from my original code so feel free to change anything: https://gist.github.com/HenryB7/ac50aa9c69af79c14a6a1dcc01fb798a

Comment: maybe you should show it on similar page [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: BTW: first I would send all arguments to Ladder in `__init__` and set shape and pos in `__init__` without using `ladderShape`, `ladderPos`. And then I could create list directly - `ladders = [Ladder(....), Ladder(....), ...]`. The same with `Snake()` and list `snakes`.

Comment: BTW: I found few mistakes in my code which I already changed but I see one of them in your code - instead of `for x in number_of_players:` has to be `for x in range(number):`

Comment: There is no need to repeate word `Ladder` in all function's names - you could have shape(), `pos()`, `draw()` instread of `ladderShape()`, `ladderPos()`, `drawLadder()`. The same with `Snake`. And then you can keep ladders and snakes on one list and then you can draw - `for x in all_objects: x.draw()` and you don't have to check `if isinstance(x, Snake): x.drawSnake() elif isinstance(x, Ladder): x.drawLadder()`